# vincular CSS num projeto Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring-mvc

Observem bem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu tentei colocar assim na pagina;

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="resources/css/style.css/>
```

tentei assim também;

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="resources/css/style2.css/>
```

mas não pegou as configurações de CSS.

========ATUALIZAÇÃO==============================

EU TENTEI assim também ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="resources.css/style.css/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="resources.css/style2.css/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na sua classe de configuração do Spring MVC que estende a classe [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html), o método [addResourceHandlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) deve ser sobrescrito ficando desta forma:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/views/resources/");
}
```

O primeiro parâmetro `"/resources/**"` informa qual URL irá acessar os recursos estáticos(css, js, img...), o segundo parâmetro informa em qual pasta está os recursos `"/views/resources/"`

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]